# Magento 2.1 Notes for this Order no email customer option

Tags: magento-2.1

We have a Magento 2.1 store we are setting up and just created a test order and noticed in the Notes for this Order section of the order admin panel there is no way to click a checkbox or anything to be able to email the customer the order note?

I am not sure if this is that way magento 2.1 is it doesn't allow you to email order notes to a customer or if I have a setting that I might need to enable? All I have is a "visable in frontend" checkbox?

Answer (score 0):

You can go to Store>Configuration>Sales>Sales Email

Over there you can see "Order Comments". From there you can select what email template to send for order comments. Also if needed you can disable email update for order comments.